# Unable to query a document from MongoDB Atlas Cluster using 'eq' operation

Tags: java, mongodb, eclipse, find, mongodb-atlas

I am unable to query a document from MongoDB Atlas Cluster using `eq` operation. All the documents are fetched, and filtering is not working.

I have tried all the available options to find a document from the collection using **eq** operator but ***couldn't able to fetch the document***. Please help. Here is the code that i am working on:

```
    MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI("mongodb+srv://sumitraojha:sumitra@cluster0-tkx83.mongodb.net/customer?retryWrites=true&w=majority");
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(uri);
    System.out.println("The connection to mongoDB is established");

    //MongoDB Database connection
    MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("customer");
    System.out.println("The Queried data is:");
    MongoCursor<Document> custcursor1 = custDetails.find(eq("Fname", "Rebecca")).iterator();
    //System.out.println(custcursor1);
    try {
        while (custcursor1.hasNext()) {
            Document document = (Document) custcursor1.next();
            System.out.println(document.toJson());
        }
    } finally {
        // TODO: handle finally clause
        custcursor1.close();
    }  
    //FindIterable<Document> findIt = database.getCollection("customerDetails").find(eq("Fname","PQR"));
    FindIterable<Document> findIt = custDetails.find(eq("Fname","PQR"));
    //System.out.println(findIt);

    MongoCursor<Document> cursor = findIt.iterator();
    System.out.println(cursor); 
    try { 
        while(cursor.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(cursor.next().toJson()); 
            Document custdoc = Document.parse(cursor.next().toJson()); 
            System.out.println(custdoc); 
        } 
    } finally { 
        cursor.close(); 
    }
```

[here is the sample output for your reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLxGO.png)

Comment: `"Fname"` is not a top-level field in your documents, it is in a document embedded in the `customer` field.

Comment: Thanks a lot. i had overlooked this simple thing. thanks again for the quick help.:)